# Mailbox/Email Hosting Service with an API 

Tags: api, email, hosting

I'm trying to create an email service web app but I do not want to deal with mail servers.
I'm only interested in creating the front-end web interface.

The ideal situation would be when a new user signs up, I create a mailbox on said service.
I would also use the service to pull emails from mailboxes, write to these mailboxes ( email tags) and possibly use the same service to send mail.

The closest thing I could find was mailGun.com but at this time it stores mailbox passwords using plain text -_- . They stated that this will be resolved in the future.

I also looked at postmark and emailYak.

Anyone know of any other services ?

Comment: **update** Mailgun [deprecated](http://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#mailboxes) the mailbox feature

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've not used them, but how about [context.io](http://context.io/)

Comment: I did know about contextIO but at first glance did not think it was what I was looking for. Just took another look at the site and **yep** this is what I wanted, an application that connects to mailboxes and provides a rest API. Thank you !

Comment: Just to let you guys know - context.io doesn't provide email hosting it's just an api which uses your current email server to send and receive email

Comment: context.io is no more as of 2022.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Qboxmail that provides API for Email Hosting:

http://www.qboxmail.com/it/documentazione/api-email-hosting